# How to remove that nasty color layer in the Windows® 7 image viewer?

Tags: windows, windows-10, images, pictures, color-profiles

Since several months now, I accidentally added an orange layer in Windows® 7 image viewer. It prevent all pictures from being seen normally. I can’t remember anything about how I set it.

example :[image]
The same image inside the image viewer : [image]
An another example : [image]
inside the image viewer : [image]

This does so with every kind of images and every formats. How to remove this ?

Of course I still have the windows rt image viewer but it doesn’t support many format the desktop version supports. So even if the question was asked before, it doesn’t solve the problem for Windows® 10.

The default installed colour profile is the 1 shipped with the cd which was in the monitor box *(that is the vendor supplied profile which is specially designed for my screen)*

Comment: Have you seen this Microsoft [forum thread](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-pictures/window-7-photo-viewer-shows-pictures-with-orange/e5d31c5e-ae84-4ebd-bbe9-9428f410560b?auth=1)?

Comment: @Burgi : Starting with [tag:windows-10], many configuration settings are no longer available in the classical control panel *(aka control.exe)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google brought some results:

1. Control Panel
2. Type "Color" in the search bar and click on the green color management link
3. In the dialog that appears, tick the box under your monitor name which says "use my settings for this device"
4. Click on the Add button
5. A list of color profiles will display. Select `sRGBIEC611966-2.1` and click OK
6. Click on the "Set as default profile" button and then Close button

Source: http://www.sevenforums.com/music-pictures-video/8081-windows-photo-viewer-background-yellow-color-fix.html

Comment: I have the windows 10 control panel…

Comment: You may want to explicitly list your OS, the only information given is in the title and refers to Windows 7.

Comment: How did you get the Windows 7 picture viewer on Win 10?

Comment: @Burgi : windows 10 feature both of them *(the same way it feature windows media player and groove)*. The default viewer is for the windows rt plateform and is architecture neutral *(bytecode)*. The classical one is simply referred as the desktop version.

Comment: Well I never...

Comment: @Burgi : perhaps you never tried to open an image with an another application. Or maybe you never tried to preview something, like a picture in the dds file format ?

Comment: @user2284570 I just assumed it had been removed

Comment: @Burgi : there are many picture formats that aren’t supported by the new viewer, and for these, the old desktop viewer is still the default one. That’s why I waited so much time for asking that question *(that is, [until I had to deal with 1 of those unsupported format](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/30454/2341))*

Comment: @user2284570 None the less, does the solution work? You can `WinKey+S` to search for Color Management, then the steps continue the same.

Comment: I am skeptical about this for two reasons: 1) the ICC profile affect ALL color, and the window/menu bar seems unaffected; 2) the ICC profile affects color transform on the display only and the screenshots should be normal (i.e. the color correction is monitor based, not file based.) Perhaps it is profile based, but via a local software configuration (or video driver control panel override) instead

Comment: @root : as stated, it doesn’t and`WinKey+S`simply open the windows menu.

Comment: @Yorik : yeah, it only affect photoviewer.dll *(which is the classic picture viewer)*

Comment: The sevenforum link that root provided has a photo viewer registry setting you can check, maybe page 2 (?)

Comment: @user2284570 Both Color Management and the Windows 10 Control Panel exist as they were in Windows 7. That shouldn't stop you trying this, although I don't know if it's actually the solution. http://i.imgur.com/YlO94FQ.jpg

Comment: @Jonno whether I remove all color profiles or whether I set the color profile of my manufacturer as default, nothing is changing.

Comment: @Yorik : I tried the registry hack and it made the orange layer even stronger.